# The type of one of the expressions int he join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'join'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently trying to join a column from another table to an existing table and return it to the view in MVC 4

```
var q = from accCo in db.AccControls
        join accCom in db.AccCompanies
        on new { accCo.ControlCode } equals
        new { ControlCode = accCom.Code }

        where accCo.ControlCode == Request.QueryString["ControlCode"]
        orderby accCom.Code
        select new Combined{ AccControls = accCo, AccCompoanies = accCom };

return View(q);
```

But I'm getting the above error

Comment: Is accCo.ControlCode or accCom.Code nullable?

Comment: have you tried = on accCo.ControlCode == accom.Code? Or are these different types?

Comment: accCo.ControlCode doesn't allow nulls. accCom.Code does allow nulls

Comment: then look at my answer bellow :)

Comment: for sure, they should be from the same type to be able to do that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If any of the columns you join on is nullable, you will need to change it to .Value

```
on new { accCo.ControlCode } equals
            new { ControlCode = accCom.Code.Value }
```

or you can use this

```
var q = from accCo in db.AccControls
    join accCom in db.AccCompanies
    where accCom.Code != null
    on new { accCo.ControlCode } equals
    new { ControlCode = accCom.Code }

    where accCo.ControlCode == Request.QueryString["ControlCode"]
    orderby accCom.Code
    select new Combined{ AccControls = accCo, AccCompoanies = accCom };
```

Comment: That's got rid of the join error, thanks, but now I'm getting:
String does not contain definition for Value and no extension method value accepting a first argument of type string could not be found

Comment: Then you shouldn't use .Value but filter null records

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var q = from accCom in db.AccCompanies
        let accCo = db.AccControls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ControlCode == accCom.Code)
        where accCo.ControlCode == Request.QueryString["ControlCode"]
              && accCo != null
        orderby accCom.Code
        select new Combined { AccControls = accCo, AccCompoanies = accCom };
```

Comment: Why would that help anything?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps its the `Request.QueryString["ControlCode"]`

try decalre it outside the linq qry, like this:

```
var code = Request.QueryString["ControlCode"];

var q = from accCo in db.AccControls
        join accCom in db.AccCompanies
        on new { accCo.ControlCode } equals
        new { ControlCode = accCom.Code }

        where accCo.ControlCode == code //EDIT
        orderby accCom.Code
        select new Combined{ AccControls = accCo, AccCompoanies = accCom };
```