# ASP.NET The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Tags: asp.net

I am currently using LINQ to get data from a DatabaseContext instance.

```
using (var dbContext = new DataContext("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=BillingApp;Integrated Security=True;"))
                {
                    Table<ServiceContract> service_contracts = dbContext.GetTable<ServiceContract>();
                    Table<Corporation> corporations = dbContext.GetTable<Corporation>();
                    IEnumerable<ServiceContract> tmp = from sc in service_contracts
                                                       join corp in corporations on sc.corp_id equals corp.corporation_id
                                                       select sc.corp_id;
                }
```

however, the system show red line under the word - join. The message is as follows:

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'
```

Comment: Check this !! May be your case match too.. (Nullable columns) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752758/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-int-he-join-clause-is-incorrect-type-inferen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345039/type-inference-failed-in-a-call-to-join-on-nullable-and-non-nullable-int refer This It will Definately Help You. :-)